# Postgis installation on Ubuntu 15.10 server gives dependencies error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to install *postgis* on Ubuntu server 15.10 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2
```

but I am getting following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2 : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
```

Comment: You should ask that one on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Question was moved to http://askubuntu.com/q/759417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it. The problem was with my sources.list file. It was missing the right postgresql repository. I edited the sources file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

There I had to change the line:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main
```

to:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt wily-pgdg main
```